# Compiling Python Package on Windows

Tags: python-3.x, python-packaging, python-install

My apology if this may not be the right place to post my question. I recently had to update Windows 10 system on a Lenovo Yoga 910 laptop. Following the system update, I successfully installed Python 3.7.2, which I primarily use with [Abjad](http://abjad.mbrsi.org/installation.html), a music composition package.

The installation of the Abjad package was successful and all required components for the package appear to be successfully installed and callable from the terminal. However, when I compile it I get this error message:

```
   Python 3.7.2 (tags/v3.7.2:9a3ffc0492, Dec 23 2018, 23:09:28) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import abjad
>>> note = abjad.Note()
>>> abjad.show(note)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\nagym\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\abjad\top\show.py", line 51, in show
    result = abjad.persist(argument).as_pdf(**keywords)
  File "C:\Users\nagym\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\abjad\system\PersistenceManager.py", line 234, in as_pdf
    **keywords
  File "C:\Users\nagym\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\abjad\system\PersistenceManager.py", line 67, in as_ly
    lilypond_file = illustrate_function(**keywords)
  File "C:\Users\nagym\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\abjad\core\Component.py", line 118, in __illustrate__
    lilypond_file = abjad.LilyPondFile.new(self)
  File "C:\Users\nagym\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\abjad\lilypondfile\LilyPondFile.py", line 990, in new
    use_relative_includes=use_relative_includes,
  File "C:\Users\nagym\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\abjad\lilypondfile\LilyPondFile.py", line 147, in __init__
    token = LilyPondVersionToken()
  File "C:\Users\nagym\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\abjad\lilypondfile\LilyPondVersionToken.py", line 27, in __init__
    version_string = abjad_configuration.get_lilypond_version_string()
  File "C:\Users\nagym\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\abjad\system\AbjadConfiguration.py", line 412, in get_lilypond_version_string
    proc = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
  File "C:\Users\nagym\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\subprocess.py", line 775, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Users\nagym\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\subprocess.py", line 1178, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
>>>
```

I don't think that the problem I have may necessarily be related to the above Python package installation, given that the same package compiles just fine on Linux and Mac systems. In fact, the package worked perfectly on Windows before the update.

While I have already inquired about this on relevant Abjad forum sites, I wonder if perhaps some folks on this list with more extensive Windows-Python background may be able to read the above error message and point me in the right direction? Could it be that what I'm experiencing may be more like an IT issue, or perhaps a lack of proper Windows setup?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resetting the PC solved the problem. I'm still not sure what was the cause of the problem and why Python didn't want to compile the package earlier.

I appreciate the opportunity to ask the question.